# Github pages unable to show all html files

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble with Posting my project to github pages. It has multiple html files and one of the pages does not work and reports page not found

That is the page the highscore does not work. How would i resolve this?

https://tgriff21.github.io/familyguy-trivia/

this is the repository
https://github.com/tgriff21/familyguy-trivia

Comment: you need to put all pages inside the docs folder to have them displayed in [github pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site).

Comment: Which page in question is not showing up?

Comment: @newbiedev You can set the repo root as the location for GitHub Pages to use the files

Comment: The links are not relative. For example the link to the game (`https://tgriff21.github.io/pages/game.html`) should point to `https://tgriff21.github.io/trivia/pages/game.html` instead. The files are there but the links are not correct.

Comment: Hi, Im not sure how to use docs versus root. The docs did not work @newbiedev

Comment: @theusaf The game file and the highscore is not working